# Django Template not displaying model data, showing blank page

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

Django Template not displaying model data, showing blank page
...Have a look at it:

models.py

```
class appointment(models.Model):

patient_name1= models.ForeignKey('identity')
appoint_date= models.DateTimeField('Appoinment time and date')
patient_info=  models.TextField()
fees= models.CharField('Fees',max_length=100,blank=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Appointment Detail'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Appoinment Details'
    ordering = ['appoint_date']

def __str__(self):
    return '%s (%s)' % (self. patient_name1, self.appoint_date)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import identity, appointment 


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'appoint/index.html')

def appointment_list(request):
    Appointments = appointment.objects.all()
    context = {'Appointments': Appointments}
    return render(request, 'appoint/appointment_list.html', context)
```

appointment_list.html

```
<p>{{Appointments.patient_name1}}</p>
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^appointment_list/$', views.appointment_list,  name='appointment_list'),
url(r'^aboutme/$', views.aboutme, name='about_us'),
url(r'^contact/$', views.contact, name='contact_us'),
url(r'^apply_appoint/$', views.apply_appoint, name='apply_appoint'),
]
```

please help me i am new to Django 1.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to iterate over the queryset and then access object's attribute:

```
<p>
  {% for appointment in Appointments %}
      {{ appointment.patient_name1 }}
  {% endfor %}
</p>
```

`Appointments` is a queryset which is a list of instances of Appointment class.

and you need to name your classes with Capital letter btw. Normally objects are in lowercase and class names begin with Capital letter.

Answer (score 1):

`Appointments` is a list of model objects you need to loop over them in template
like this:

```
<p>
{% for object in Appointments %}
  {{ object.patient_name1 }} , {{ object.appoint_date }}
{% endfor %}
</p>
```